# array of elements clicked jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have multiple `div` elements, but they all have different class:

```
<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="b">2</div>
<div class="c">3</div>
```

Is there a way I could, using JQuery, register which I click first in an array.
Like I:

- First click on `.a`
- Second click on `.c`
- Third click on `.b`

At it will give me the following output:

```
["class: a, content: 1", "class: c, content: 3", "class: b, content: 2"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to form array.

```
var clickData = [];
$('.a,.b,.c').click(function(){
    clickData.push('class: '+this.className+', content: '+ this.innerText); 
    console.log(clickData)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the click on div, and append its class and html in array on click of it:

```
var clickarr = [];
$('.a, .b, .c').click(function(){
  clickarr.push("class: " + $(this).attr('class')+ ", content: " + $(this).text() );
});
```